# Search Mismatch in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

I noticed the following strange quirk when working with Mongo in a Meteor stack:

[image: Quick]

You'll notice that I searched for `id: 680844728003375168` but got a document with `id: 680844728003375104.000000` instead. This has worked for me on all values from `00` to `68` for the last two digits. Is this a bug? Or an expected, but odd, behavior for MongoDB?

Comment: Have you tried running this same query within mongo terminal directly rather RoboMongo?

Comment: Modify your query to use the standard operation for matching fields e.g. field({ id: 68084472.... }) rather $eq.  Technically both should return the same output, but let's see if that returns the same document.  I'd also like to see the result of $eq op in mongo's direct terminal rather robomongo.  Can't call this a bug just yet!

Comment: @MKNWebSolutions I've tried both of your suggestions already; neither had any effect on the output. I've also noticed that `$lte`/`$gte` also include the value even when out of bounds, same with `$lt`/`$gt`.